# Bacteria on fingers. Syntax for crossed random effects with random slopes but not intercepts in MASS::glmmPQL

Tags: r, glm, lme4

I have non-normal data (bacteria on fingers after touching surfaces with and without gloves) so using glmmPQL from the MASS package. I have one categorical predictor (Gloves), a repeated measurement variable (NumberContacts) and Participants who did the experiment gloved and ungloved so are crossed. I'd like to use the Participant variable as a random effect with random slope (but not intercept as they have 0 bacteria to start with). I can't figure out the syntax for random effects with random slope but not random intercept. Could you show me how to do this please?

So far I have:

```
require(MASS)
PQL <- glmmPQL(bacteria ~ Gloves+ NumberContacts, ~1|Participant,
               family =    gaussian(link = "log"),
               #weights = varIdent(form = ~1 | NumberContacts),
               #correlation = corAR1(NumberContacts),
               data = na.omit(Ksub), 
               verbose = F)
```

Bacteria on fingers after each contact

[image: bacteria vs contacts]

Density plots of bacteria on fingers after each contact
[image]

Comment: Doesn't it belong to Cross Validated?

Comment: I thought about it. I'm asking for syntax for random slopes in glmmPQL not method or theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#model-specification, which notes that `(0+x|group)` or `(-1+x|group)` specifies "random slope of x within group: no variation in intercept."

The model specifications in the example below are equivalent:

```
library(MASS)
library(lme4)

fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (0 + Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
fm2 <- glmmPQL(Reaction ~ Days, random = ~ 0 + Days | Subject, 
  family = gaussian, data = sleepstudy)
```

Comment: I've trawled through that and also (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13166/rs-lmer-cheat-sheet). But they're for lme4 and don't work for glmmPQL from MASS. Unless I'm doing something stupid. Could you show explicity what it would look like in my example please?

Comment: After reading your question a few times I still can't quite figure out what the model is that you have in mind. But if you can write out your model using the lme4 specification it shouldn't be too hard to translate it into the nlme form.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Could you please clarify the following: So do I read that to mean all the subjects are tested on all the days (i.e. crossed)? If you write (~1 | Subjects), what does it mean? And lastly, what does the tilde (~) mean next to the 1?

Comment: The comments section is not designed for extended discussion. I would suggest reviewing the help documentation for the `lme` function in the `nlme` package for details about the model specification syntax. Look under the description of the `random` argument.  If you have follow-up questions, I would suggest opening a new question.

Comment: Ok, could you at least clarify (0 + Days | Subject) in words please.

Comment: The slope for Days (i.e. the relationship between Days and the dependent variable) varies by Subject, but not the intercept.

Comment: (1) you'll also need a `-1` or `+0` in the fixed effects model if you want to suppress the intercept completely; (2) a reproducible example would help a lot (or at least saying what "doesn't work" means more precisely); (3) not really sure why you need `MASS::glmmPQL` - this model should work with `lme4::glmer` (which is better-supported)

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker, (1) I'm trying to say that the quantity of bacteria on fingers depends on the individual participant (hence the random effects).  But all their intercepts must be 0 as they have no bacteria to start with (hence fixed intercept). Reasonable? (2) I've asked about method on stats.stack https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/362306/bacteria-picked-up-on-fingers-after-multiple-surface-contacts-non-normal-data/362496#362496 . (3)  Residuals vs fitted were massive (>1000) and funnelling, so thought that to be problematic.

Comment: Since you've asked a second time, can you please either accept @WeihuangWong's answer or delete/close this question so it doesn't attract redundant/wasted effort?